# Create SuiteCommerce Page sending email in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

I want to build form sending email.

As you know there is no sending email function in javascript. 
But in SuiteScript there is nlapiSendEmail function.

Can I use this function in this page?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a Service and Model file and call them from your client side code. These files are run server-side so you can use nlapiSendEmail.